# Generate a random file of 0's and 1's

Tags: linux, windows, random, binaryfiles

I would like to generate a random file of size 2MB which consists only of 0's and 1's in either Linux/Windows for one of my projects. I tried this command in Linux:

```
$ time dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=1M count=2
```

but urandom only takes random data from the kernel and just copies to the file which is not what I need. Any ideas regarding this?

Comment: Why is the random data you are getting not acceptable? "Not what you need" is not very helpful when it otherwise seems to match what you are asking for. Or do you mean you want it expanded to a sequence of ASCII representing the characters 0 and 1?

Comment: I am just getting some random data by using the above command. But I want a file which contains only randomly generated 0's and 1's

Comment: So ASCII? Pipe through something like `perl -0777 -ne 'print unpack("b*")'`

Comment: That's exactly what you request in your question... to generate a random pattern of 0's and 1's and store them in a file.   You say urandom only takes random data from the kernel... Where do you want it to get data from? and you say then that it copies to a file which is not what you need.. What do you need? you have written in the question to generate a random **file**???  By the way, you have tagged your question as `binaryfiles` So i'll suppose you want it binary.  Can you edit your question and decide what do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **EDIT**: All these solutions are pretty bad in practice. tripleee's proposal (pipe the output of /dev/urandom to `perl -0777 -ne 'print unpack("b*")'`) in questions' comments is much better.

Do you need something fast ? Otherwise you can try that (took ~2mn for me):

```
$ time (for i in `seq 1 $((2*1024*1024))`; 
  do echo -n $(($RANDOM%2)); done > random.txt)
```

You can make it faster by calling $RANDOM less, for example:

```
$ time (i=$((2*1024*1024)); a=0; while [ $i -gt 0 ]; do if [ $a -lt 2 ]; then 
a=$RANDOM; fi; echo -n "$(($a%2))"; let a=$a/2; let i=$i-1; done > random.txt)
```

It's nearly 4 times faster in my case. What it does is that it extracts right bit of the number until there's no more 1 in the number. It may therefore slightly be biaised toward 1.

However, if you want a fast solution, you should clearly not use a shell scripting language. You can do it easily in python (this takes ~2 seconds in my case):

```
$ time (python -c "import random; print(''.join('{0}'.format(n) for n in 
random.sample([0,1]*16*1024*1024, 2*1024*1024)));" > random.txt)
```

Here I'm randomly sampling a big list of 0 and 1. However, I'm not sure of the effect of sampling on the quality of the randomness. If the list is huge compared to the sample, I think it should provide a good quality result but here it's only 8 times bigger so it probably has a measurable impact.

Note that randomness is not as easy as it may seem. The output of the solutions I propose here don't all have the same properties and verifying which one it has is often complex. You may want to trade performance for 'better' randomness, in which case this version in python may be better (~6 seconds in my case):

```
$ time (python -c "from __future__ import print_function; import random;
[print(random.randint(0,1), end='') for i in range(0, 2*1024*1024)];" > random.txt)
```

Here, random.randint should provide an evenly distributed result.

Comment: generating the string directly from the binary value would be thousands of times faster than using just a single bit from the 32 or 64 bits that were generated each cycle and throw away the others

Answer (score 1):

Colin's solutions are so **immensely inefficient** because one method creates a huge list then choose from that (so it won't work if you want a larger file), and the other produces only 1 character each cycle

```bash
$ time (python3 -c "import random; print(''.join('{0}'.format(n) for n in 
random.sample([0,1]*16*1024*1024, 2*1024*1024)));" > /dev/null)

real    0m4,034s
user    0m3,856s
sys     0m0,137s

$ time (python3 -c "from __future__ import print_function; import random;
[print(random.randint(0,1), end='') for i in range(0, 2*1024*1024)];" > /dev/null)

real    0m6,461s
user    0m6,435s
sys     0m0,016s
```

[tripleee's solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251188/generate-a-random-file-of-0s-and-1s#comment58217940_35251188) is much much much faster

```bash
$ time (perl -077 -ne 'print unpack("b*")' < /dev/urandom | head -c2M >/dev/null)

real    0m0,007s
user    0m0,006s
sys     0m0,003s
```

`head -c2M` here is to limit the output to 2 MB

Theoretically it should be even faster to process 8 bytes in a cycle instead of just 1 byte like that, although I have no idea how to make it more efficient with perl

```bash
$ time (</dev/urandom perl -nle 'BEGIN{$/=\8; $,=""} printf("%.64b", unpack("Q"))' |
head -c2M >/dev/null)

real    0m0,027s
user    0m0,019s
sys     0m0,010s
```

In [What's the fastest way to generate a 1 GB text file containing random digits?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/323845/44425) there are answers that can produce ***decimal* digits with space separator** in the speed of **GBs or tens of GBs per second**. Generating only *binary* values without any spaces like in your case should be **magnitudes faster**. I've adapted some of those answers to generate 0s and 1s. Here are some benchmarks on my Ubuntu 18.04 VM (Core i7-8700, 2GB RAM):

```bash
$ time (LC_ALL=C tr '\0-\377' '[0*128][1*128]' </dev/urandom | head -c2M >/dev/null)

real    0m0,012s
user    0m0,003s
sys     0m0,012s


$ time (jot -s "" -r -c $((2*1024*1024)) 48 49) >/dev/null

real    0m0,297s
user    0m0,279s
sys     0m0,008s

$ time (shuf -r -n $((2*1024*1024)) -i 0-1 -z | tr -d "\0" >/dev/null)

real    0m0,383s
user    0m0,384s
sys     0m0,000s
```

In fact `/dev/urandom` isn't even fast enough and can be replaced with `</dev/zero openssl enc -aes-128-ctr -nosalt -pass file:/dev/urandom` to provide an even faster random byte stream on CPUs with the [AES instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set). Here's the timing for outputting a 20MB file (as the running time of the above `tr` command for 2MB is so short which makes `time` returns a wildly varied result)

```bash
$ time (</dev/zero openssl enc -aes-128-ctr -nosalt -pass file:/dev/urandom 2> /dev/null |
LC_ALL=C tr '\0-\377' '[0*128][1*128]' | head -c20M >/dev/null)

real    0m0,023s
user    0m0,016s
sys     0m0,023s

$ time (</dev/zero openssl enc -aes-128-ctr -nosalt -pass file:/dev/urandom 2> /dev/null |
perl -077 -ne 'print unpack("b*")' | head -c20M >/dev/null)

real    0m0,038s
user    0m0,024s
sys     0m0,019s

$ time (</dev/zero openssl enc -aes-128-ctr -nosalt -pass file:/dev/urandom 2> /dev/null |
jot -s "" -r -c $((20*1024*1024)) 48 49 >/dev/null)

real    0m2,820s
user    0m2,820s
sys     0m0,000s
```

Comment: Yeah, my solutions were pretty bad in retrospective :-) tripleee one's is clearly a better approach